# RabbitMQ - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I am trying to use a simple RabbitMQ example and it gives me:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory".

I have amqp-client-4.0.2.jar, slf4j-1.7.25.zip, slf4j-jdk14.jar.zip and log4j-1.2.15.jar on my Build Path.

My code is very basic and I tried a lot of the advices from here on simillar matters, I changed different types of slfj, but it still doesn`t work.

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost(HOST);
factory.setUsername(USER);
factory.setPassword(TOKEN);
factory.setVirtualHost(VHOST);
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

String message = "Test!";
channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, QUEUE_NAME, null,              message.getBytes());
System.out.println(" [x] Sent '" + message + "' with id=");

channel.close();
connection.close();
```

Full error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:     org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.<clinit>(AMQConnection.java:49)
at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.<init>(ConnectionFactory.java:91)
at ro.test.RMQ_Send_LocalHost.main(RMQ_Send_LocalHost.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the slf4j-api dependency to your application:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but is not a Maven Project.

Comment: The answer remains the same, you can just download the JAR file and include it in your project without maven.

Comment: Well, it actualy worked, meaning that it gives other error. That would be: SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect. I even left only the jar you sent me and deleted the other ones, like it says on that link and it gives me the same error.

Comment: Good to see it works. The error you're getting now is because there is no specific logger implementation found. You can get rid of this by using the slf4j-simple library.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved it. After all the proper jars, slfj-api1.8 and slfj-simple 1.8, it worked. The problem was related to some kind of incompatibility beetwen earlier versions of slfj-simple.